# Return object from Promise-expected function

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I wrote this function to get and cache some datas from API.

```
export class MyService {
  static items: Array<Post> = null;

  async getItems(): Promise<Array<Post>> {
    if (MyService.items) {
      return MyService.items;
    }
    else {
      return this.doRequest();      
    }
  }

  private async doRequest: Promise<Array<Post>> {
    // get items from API.
  }
}
```

As I know, I must return a Promise from `getItems` function, something like: `return Promise.resolve(MyService.items)`, so why (and how) above function still work - I'm returning an object from a Promise-expected function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function that is preceded by the `async` keyword will automatically wrap its return value in a promise. There is no need to do so manually using `Promise.resolve()` or the like, although doing so is also perfectly fine.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function:

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. **When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.**  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

Emphasis mine. That process happens automatically as a consequence of declaring the function using the `async` keyword.

Additionally, typescript is aware of that, so as long as you return a value that adheres to `Array<Category>`, typescript is satisfied, since it knows that it will be automatically wrapped into a `Promise<Array<Category>>`.